# Are the output dimensions of the first and second convolutional layer in YOLO paper correct?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, architecture, yolo, convolution-arithmetic

I was reading the last version of [the YOLO paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640) available in Arxiv, and I don't fully understand the output dimensions (I understand width and height, but not depth) of the first and second convolutional layers.

[image]

Shouldn't the output of the first layer be 112x112x64? Shouldn't the output of the second layer be 56x56x192? I thought (and this is the case after the 3rd layer) that the depth of the ouput of a conv layer is equal to the number of filters of this layer. This is why after the first conv layer (that contains 64 filters) I would expect an output depth of 64. And the same for the second conv layer that contains 192 filters, I would expect the output to have a depth of 192.

Comment: In the diagram, they write 7x7x64-s-2. What is the meaning of the notation "64-s-2"? That's probably going to answer your question. Feel free to answer your own question below, if you find an answer to it.

Comment: I don't think that's the solution. s-2 means stride of 2, and this stide results in the input dimensions being divided by 2 in the output. This is why after the first two s-2 layers (one conv and one maxpool), the 448x448 input is transformed into a 112x112 output. The second s-2 maxpool layer, transforms its 112x112 input into a 56x56 output. An so on. However, this is not related in principle to the third dimension (depth). Thanks in any case!

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that s was related to stride. The other idea is that 64*3 = 192. Are they using a 3d convolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case anyone is struggling with the same problem. It seems that they were simply typos in the original paper. I have downloaded the author's framework [Darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/), as well as the configuration and [weight](http://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov1/yolov1.weights) files for YOLOv1.

Then, the architecture can be tested with one sample image using this command:

```
./darknet yolo test cfg/yolov1/yolo.cfg yolov1.weights data/person.jpg
```

The output of this command also prints the full architecure of the net. There, I see the expected depth values after the first (depth of 64) and second max layers (depth of 192):

```
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
       0 Create CUDA-stream - 0 
     Create cudnn-handle 0 
    conv     64       7 x 7/ 2    448 x 448 x   3 ->  224 x 224 x  64 0.944 BF
       1 max                2x 2/ 2    224 x 224 x  64 ->  112 x 112 x  64 0.003 BF
       2 conv    192       3 x 3/ 1    112 x 112 x  64 ->  112 x 112 x 192 2.775 BF
       3 max                2x 2/ 2    112 x 112 x 192 ->   56 x  56 x 192 0.002 BF
```

So it seems clear to me that the 192 and 256 depth values after the first and second max layer on the figure in the question are just typos.